# Argument of type '{ query: { orderByChild: string; equalTo: string; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FirebaseListFactoryOpts'

Tags: typescript, firebase, ionic3, angularfire2

[image]I'm trying to query a list from firebase but I'm getting this error:

Argument of type '{ query: { orderByChild: string; equalTo: string; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FirebaseListFactoryOpts'.

```
this.afDB.list('/category', {query: {
    orderByChild: "type",
    equalTo: "place"
}})
```

Comment: That doesn't look anything like the code samples you see on this page: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/rtdb/querying-lists.md

Comment: @DougStevenson

I already tried that but it isn't work either. getting: `[ts] Value of type '(ref: any) => any' has no properties in common with type 'FirebaseListFactoryOpts'. Did you mean to call it?`

Comment: @ridwaili you are using an old version of Angularfiredatabase . You need to import the correct version from `angularfire2/database` as per the document and then pass an arrow function as second parameter in this format `(ref: DatabaseReference) => DatabaseQuery;`

Comment: @Niladri thanks works after importing the right one `angularfire2/database` :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you all for your help.

I was importing deprecated one, and here is the fix:

```
import { AngularFireDatabase} from 'angularfire2/database';
```

then, just follow the [angularfire2 documentation](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/rtdb/querying-lists.md) :

```
this.afDB.list('/category', ref => 
ref.orderByChild('type').equalTo('place'))
.valueChanges()
.subscribe(categoryItems => {
  this.category = categoryItems;
  loadingPopup.dismiss()
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To add a query to a list call, you use pass a callback rather than a straight object. See [here](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/rtdb/querying-lists.md) for list querying docs.

In your case you would want something like

```
this.afDB.list('/category', ref => ref.orderByChild('type').equalTo('place'));
```

Comment: I already tried that but it isn't work either.
getting: 

`[ts] Value of type '(ref: any) => any' has no properties in common with type 'FirebaseListFactoryOpts'. Did you mean to call it?`

Comment: The callback function works with the newer `AngularFireDatabase` class from  `/src/database/database.ts`, OPs example is from the older `/src/database-deprecated/firebase_list_factory.ts`.